# Rails: how to store and retrieve data from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, has-many

I am developing a project in rails with models as

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bills
end

class Bill < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :party
    has_many :details
end

class Detail< ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :bill
end
```

My controller class

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_party, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

        def index
            @parties = Party.all
        end

        def show
            @parties = Party.find(params[:id])
        end


        def new
          @party = Party.new
          @bill = Bill.new
        end


        def edit
            @parties = Party.find(params[:id])
        end

        def create
          @party = Party.new(party_params)
          @bill = Bill.new

          respond_to do |format|
            if @party.save
              format.html { redirect_to @party, notice: 'Party was           successfully created.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @party }
            else
              format.html { render :new }
              format.json { render json: @party.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end

        def update
          respond_to do |format|
            if @party.update(party_params)
              format.html { redirect_to @party, notice: 'Party was           successfully updated.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @party }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @party.errors, status:           :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end


        def destroy
          @party.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to parties_url, notice: 'Party was successfully destroyed.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          end
        end

        private

          def set_party
            @party = Party.find(params[:id])
          end
         def party_params
             params.require(:party).permit(:name, :address)
          end
      end
```

Now i want to store the parameters of Detail class and also show it in views.

1. Should i use the Party controller for doing it?
2. How to define the routes in this case? My existing routes are:

   ```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
       root 'parties#index'
       resources :parties do
       resources :bills
      end
   end
   ```

For class Detail , how should i define routes?

3. I want to have that views displayed as independent to user. For example 
   If a user clicks on a particular bill he would be able to add details to     bill

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. To store `Detail` parameters you have to use `DetailsController`. Using `PartiesController` will not be "Rails Way" e.q. good way.
2. You may define your routes like this:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'parties#index'
  resources :parties do
    resources :bills do
      resources :details
    end
  end
end
```

3. You may generate rails scaffolds for `details` and it will fit your current needs. The views will be "independent" and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable feedback @vad. Answer 2 seems appropriate for me, for 3, you didn't get me correctly.

Comment: @Aashish, glad to help!